# Facebook API "invalid version specified"

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The Facebook API login "quickstart" page says to put the following code in your page:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '{your-app-id}',
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : '{latest-api-version}'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

App ID is easy, but what on earth is it expecting for `{latest-api-version}`?  I've tried both `'2.1'` and `'2'` and both values throw "invalid version specified" to the console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick is including `v` in the version. Some users may also have neglected to remove the {brackets}.

As of 2021-06-08 the code should look like this:

```
        version : 'v11.0'
```

Readers from the future (or the past) can view this table for different versions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/versions

Comment: This answer certainly helped me, don't understand why the downvotes.

Comment: Glad it helped. Some people just expect you to intuitively  know everything they do :)

Answer (score 1):

use: **"v5.0"** 
NOT **"{v5.0}"**

eg:

```
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxx',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v5.0'
    });
```

Comment: and now it's:   version    : 'v6.0'

Comment: 9.0 shoot me now. Is the like button passing a Turing test yet?

Comment: omegalul .. yep its 9.0 now